# I can't find sound card in /dev

Tags: debian, audio

I use Debian 8.7 jessie and I've installed it on vmware workstation. I connected a sound card to Debian virtual machine but it can't be visible in /dev, If it's not there, so where is it?

```
# lspci -nn |grep -i audio
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Ensoniq ES1371 / Creative Labs CT2518 [AudioPCI-97] [1274:1371] (rev 02)



# lsmod | grep snd
snd_ens1371            23119  2 
snd_rawmidi            27023  1 snd_ens1371
snd_seq_device         13132  1 snd_rawmidi
snd_ac97_codec        118704  1 snd_ens1371
snd_pcm                88603  2 snd_ac97_codec,snd_ens1371
snd_timer              26868  1 snd_pcm
snd                    69472  10 
snd_ac97_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_ens1371,snd_seq_device
soundcore              13031  1 snd
ac97_bus               12510  1 snd_ac97_codec
gameport               13449  1 snd_ens1371


# cat /proc/asound/modules /proc/asound/cards /proc/asound/devices

0 snd_ens1371
0 [AudioPCI       ]: ENS1371 - Ensoniq AudioPCI
                  Ensoniq AudioPCI ENS1371 at 0x2080, irq 16
2: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
3: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
4: [ 0- 1]: digital audio playback
5: [ 0- 0]: raw midi
6: [ 0]   : control
33:        : timer
```

Thanks

Comment: Please describe how you attached a piece of hardware to a virtual machine. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sound driver modules and/or the PulseAudio daemon may not have been loaded, if the (virtual?) sound card was not present at the time you installed Debian.

Use `lspci` or `lsusb` as appropriate to verify that the sound card is visible on the virtual machine. Then look into `/proc/asound` for information on sound devices with functional drivers, and `dmesg` for error messages a failure in sound module autoloading might have generated.

If you have a minimal installation, you might need to run `apt-get install pulseaudio` to get a full set of sound services installed and running.

---

According to the output of `cat /proc/asound/modules /proc/asound/cards /proc/asound/devices`, you should have:

- `/dev/snd/controlC0` for audio mixer control,
- `/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p` and `/dev/snd/pcmC0D1p` for audio output, and
- `/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c` for audio input.
- There should also be `/dev/snd/seq` and `/dev/snd/timer` for MIDI and timer interfaces, respectively.

If some or all of these are missing, it might be a problem with `udev`... but then your assertion that the card works correctly is confusing: if the device nodes are really missing, as far as I know, there should then be no way to deliver sound data to the driver. Are you sure you aren't operating in a chrooted environment, a SSH session to another host, or something else that might be showing you a different view of the `/dev` directory tree?

Comment: Hi telcoM, Thanks for your answer. PulseAudio has been installed by default. I don't use minimal installation of Debian. The sound card works correctly. But still, I can't see the sound card in /dev.

Comment: Exactly what do you expect to see? The obsolete OSS audio interfaces `/dev/dsp*` and `/dev/audio*`? Make sure the `snd-pcm-oss` is loaded to get the OSS compatibility layer for ALSA. Or the ALSA devices at `/dev/snd/*`? In that case, please edit your question and add the outputs of `lspci -nn |grep -i audio`, `lsmod | grep snd` and `cat /proc/asound/modules /proc/asound/cards /proc/asound/devices` to the question post.

Comment: Here you go, I edited it.

Comment: I've also edited my answer.